# How to sum how many 1000 in the same cell

Tags: windows

I need excel to sum how many 1000 ( in count ) are in the cell

ex. if the cell has 1000 then the count is one, if the cell has 2000 then the count is 2, etc
so, each time that i add a 1000 , cell start count

Comment: What have you tried

Comment: You mean simple math like `=FLOOR(A1/1000,1)`?

Comment: yessssss, thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### ROUNDOWN Function

If you want to know how many times `A1` can be divided by 1,000 without remainder, simply round the quotient down to the nearest integer using the [ROUNDDOWN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rounddown-function-2ec94c73-241f-4b01-8c6f-17e6d7968f53) function.

**Syntax:**
`ROUNDDOWN(number, digits)`

```
# where A1 = 2300

=ROUNDDOWN(A1/1000, 0)
=ROUNDDOWN(2300/1000, 0)
=ROUNDDOWN(2.3, 0)
=2
```

#### FLOOR Function

Per [swbbl's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1776806/how-to-sum-how-many-1000-in-the-same-cell/1776824#comment2771673_1776806) the [FLOOR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/floor-function-14bb497c-24f2-4e04-b327-b0b4de5a8886) function would achieve the same result.  It rounds down to the nearest multiple of significance.

**Syntax:**
`FLOOR(number,significance)`

```
# where A1 = 2300

=FLOOR(A1/1000, 1) 
=FLOOR(2300/1000, 1)
=FLOOR(2.3, 1)
=2
```

#### INT Function

The [INT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/int-function-a6c4af9e-356d-4369-ab6a-cb1fd9d343ef) function can also be used because it rounds a number down to the nearest integer.

**Syntax:**
`INT(number)`

```
# where A1 = 2300

=INT(A1/1000)
=INT(2300/1000)
=INT(2.3)
=2
```

Comment: **Check. My posts above deleted.** You're right, I have had this statement "in memory" a looong time, and all the time it was wrong. What I HAD above was an adapted version of `=INT(A1*POWER(10,$C$1)+0.5)/POWER(10,$C$1)` which is the general formula  to round to C1 decimals, always with the 
**last digit rounded up** if it is 5 or above.